# laravel - Uploading directory path from linux folders

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I make variable that contain the path of the directory where the uploading files will be stored. I wonder this works very well on windows but not on linux ubuntu. Perhaps the way I mention directory is wrong.

Following controller on Laravel;

```
 public function Store(Request $request){
    $data = array();
    $data['product_name'] = $request->product_name;
    $data['product_code'] = $request->product_code;
    $data['details'] = $request->details;
    $image = $request->file('logo');

    if($image){
        $image_name = date('dmy_H_s_i');
        $ext=strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $image_full_name=$image_name.'.'.$ext;
        $upload_path='home/laravel/udemy/kash';
        $image_url=$upload_path.$image_full_name;
        $success = $image->move($upload_path,$image_full_name);
        $data['logo']=$image_url;
        $product=DB::table('products')->insert($data);
        return redirect()->route('product.index')
                            ->with('success','Product Created Successfully');
    }
```

Comment: What kind of output do you get?  That might help us identify the issue.

Comment: Should you have a `/` at the start of `$upload_path` value? (`'/home/laravel/udemy/kash'`)

Comment: What is the full path to your laravel installation? ie. full path to public/index.php

Comment: xtraorange I get no image in the table. because photo i upload doesn't save in the mentioned folder

Comment: Nigel Ren when I put / before home/... then getting "Unable to create the "/home/laravel/udemy/kash" directory" error.

Comment: Kurt Friars   path is as follows: kash@TheKash:~/laravel/udemy$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon Jul 13 23:45:23 2020] PHP 7.4.7 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started

Answer (score 0):

I found solution finally. $upload_path='$home/laravel/udemy/kash/';